# Running selenium 2 tests within Jenkins against a certain selenium instance

Tags: java, grails, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I'm trying to run headless tests from Jenkins. This works fine for HTML tests when I specify the HTML test suite. But now I want to run selenium-2 tests against the same selenium server.

I tried this:

**Execute shell:**
    `export DISPLAY=":99" && java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar`

But this seems to be hang until I stopped the server manually. How do I start the selenium server in such a way that my selenium RC tests invoked through grails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special method to "start" selenium server to be used by any particular language. When you start selenium server it will start listening on a port for incoming requests. You should be having a line of code inside your tests to point your tests to the selenium server. I don't know grails. In java it would be

```
Selenium sel = new DefaultSelenium("host","port","browsername","baseurl")
```

- > host - IP of the machine where server is started
- > port - port number on which selenium server is listening. This is
  usually 4444 if you don't specify anything
- > browsername-Browser on which you want the tests to be
- > run baseURL- base URL of the web app you need to test.

The equivalent method for this in grails should get you working.

EDIT - JAVA code to start selenium server:

```
    Selenium sel;
    int port=9999;
    public static SeleniumServer server;
        public void startSeleniumServer() throws Exception {
           try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            serverSocket.close();
                    //Server not up, start it
                    try {
                     RemoteControlConfiguration rcc = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
                     rcc.setPort(port);
                     server = new SeleniumServer(false, rcc);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Could not create Selenium Server because of: "
                                + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        server.start();
                        System.out.println("Server started");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Could not start Selenium Server because of: "
                                + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (BindException e) {
                    System.out.println("Selenium server already up, will reuse...");
                }
        }

        public void stopSeleniumServer(){
            if (server != null)
              {
                 try
                 {
                    server.stop();

                 }
                 catch (Exception e)
                 {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }
              }
            System.out.println("Selenium server stopped..");
        }

    public void startSeleniumRC() throws Exception{
        sel=new DefaultSelenium("localhost",
                port,
                "*firefox",
                "http://www.google.com");
        sel.start();
    }

    public void stopSeleniumRC()
    {
        sel.shutDownSeleniumServer();
    }
```

Comment: I guess the real question is how to start the server and stop it from within Jenkins, asynchronously so as to not block the next build steps in the sequence.

Comment: Why do you want to start server in the same build? And also, is there any reason that you are starting the server as a build setup. Its better if you start your server separately. If you still want to achieve this in one build, you should start the server using the code along with your test.

Comment: I should be able to hook this into grails test phase events.